# return view with parameters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a return in my controller like this:

```
    return view('frontend.bike')->with('message', 'Bike Created');
```

It directs correctly view, however I want to pass it two variables that are needed.  Currently I have it routing via:

```
Route::get('b/{bikename}/{type?}', ['as' => 'bike', 'uses' => 'FrontendController@bike']);
```

How can I include a bikename and type to the return to make sure it goes to the correct page.

Answer (score 7):

you can get those route variable in controller as below in function arguments,

```
public function bike($bikename, $type = null){

    $type = $type ? $type:'N/A'; //optional
    $message = 'Bike Created';
    return view('frontend.bike', compact('message', 'bikename', 'type'));
}
```

**in views/frontend/bike.blade.php,**

```
{{ $message }}
{{ $bikename }}
{{ $type }}
```